# Poem in a short story?

Tags: short-story, poetry

So I need to write a short story for my university writing portfolio and I was wondering if I could put a poem in it or would that be inappropriate for a short story? And are there any short stories out there that have poems in them?

Thanks :)

Comment: This question is asking for a list, something that Stack Exchange sites don't handle well. Please edit this into a more specific question about writing or we'll have to close this.

Answer (score 1):

There are no "rules" for fiction, and appropriateness depends on whether it achieves the effect in the story you want it to.

There are many examples of novels which include poems/songs/lyrics (think Tolkien, Milne, Lewis Carroll), but I can't think of any short fiction that does so (though I am sure there must be examples.

Comment: I think I will use the poem then. Thanks so much :)